# Why we need to add asp:ScriptManager when we use teleric radgrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I want the reason for adding

```
asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true
```

`Tag` when i use `telerik radgrid`.

Otherwise it throw an error like this

```
"The control with ID 'gdSample' requires a ScriptManager on the page. 
        The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it".
```

Answer (score 1):

[ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) is required for [AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax) functionality in ASP.Net and [RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) from Telerik is AJAX based Grid.

[ScriptManager - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx)

> The ScriptManager control is central to Ajax functionality in ASP.NET.
>   The control manages all ASP.NET Ajax resources on a page. This
>   includes downloading Microsoft Ajax Library scripts to the browser and
>   coordinating partial-page updates that are enabled by using
>   UpdatePanel controls.

[RadGrid - Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx).

> Use RadGrid for ASP.NET AJAX in simple or advanced scenarios to have
>   it do anything from paging, sorting, filtering and data editing to
>   grouping and displaying hierarchical data. Achieve desktop-like
>   performance for your data-dense applications thanks to the abundance
>   of client-side features and minimal HTML and scripts loaded.